# Tag all English words in multiple text files in same directory

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to modify the code to apply to multiple text files in the same directory. The code looks as follows but there is an error "NameError: name 'output' is not defined". Can you help me to suggest improvements to the code?

```
import re

def replaceenglishwords(filename):
    mark_pattern = re.compile("\\*CHI:.*")
    word_pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z]+)")

    for line in filename:
    # Split into possible words
        parts = line.split()

        if mark_pattern.match(parts[0]) is None:
            output.write()
            continue

        # Got a CHI line
        new_line = line
        for word in parts[1:]:
            matches = word_pattern.match(word)
            if matches:
                old = f"\\b{word}\\b"
                new = f"{matches.group(1)}@s:eng"
                new_line = re.sub(old, new, new_line, count=1)
            output.write(new_line)

import glob
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    outfile = open(file.replace('.txt', '-out.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf8')
    for line in open(file, encoding='utf8'):
        print(replaceenglishwords(line), '\n', end='', file=outfile)
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: in your function `replaceenglishwords`, you try to write to a file I assume ( `output.write()` ) - you'll have to open that first or pass the file object to the function. However it seems you also try to do that in your `print` statement at the end - so what is it you try to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`replaceenglishwords` needs two parameters, one for the file you are searching and one for the file where you write you results: `replaceenglishwords(filename, output)`. It looks like your function is reading the input file line by line by itself.

Now you can open both files in your loop and pass them to `replaceenglishwords`:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    textfile = open(file, encoding='utf8')
    outfile = open(file.replace('.txt', '-out.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf8')
    replaceenglishwords(textfile, outfile)
    textfile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Dear M. Bauer, thank you for the suggestion. I tried your modification but I have obtained the following error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New folder\replace english words in one dir.py", line 29, in <module>
    replaceenglishwords(textfile, outfile)
TypeError: replaceenglishwords() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Hi Toh An, did you change the definition of your function, too? The error message looks like it does not take two arguments. It should be `def replaceenglishwords(filename, output):` The second parameter is named output, because in the function that name is used.

Comment: Thanks! I will correct it to def replaceenglishwords(filename, output):